# If I play as a Faerie Dragon can I use dragon-born feats or Fey Touched?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, races

I want to have a feat, but most feats either

- are unusable (*e.g.* weapon feats (can only use undersized weapons plus only one-handed, I use the tail to wield them)
- offer no benefit (armor feats, I have an unarmored AC of 19)
- or are not to my liking.

What remains is *Athlete*, *Dungeon Delver*, *Resilient*, *Skilled*, *Squat Nimbleness*, and *Skill Expert* (I might take that one if I cannot take the ones I ask about).

**I would like to use one of the dragon-born feats but don't know if a Faerie Dragon would be allowed to. I would also like to know if I can use the *Fey Touched* feat.**

and my DM is open, we have a 10 ft boulder, a slime, plus me as the fae dragon wizard.

P.S. A fae dragon is the same thing as a faerie dragon, a fey dragon, and it is a fairy dragon, it is related to both fairies and dragons, also I used the fae dragon page in the monster D&D handbook

Comment: Just curious...where did you *find* a Faerie/Fae Dragon playable race?

Comment: Voting to leave open, this seems like a clear case of beginner question.

Comment: Yes this is my first question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### A Faerie Dragon is neither a Dragonborn nor a Fey

By RAW, you cannot therefore take Dragonborn feats. *Fey Touched* on the other hand doesn't have any restrictions of the kind even if the name might imply otherwise. Therefore there's no problem with you taking that feat.

### Talk to your GM

Being a *Faerie Dragon* as a player character is not an official option. Your GM is already allowing something unusual. It would therefore not be problematic to allow further non-official options such as Dragonborn feats for your no -Dragonborn character. The possible balance implications are much less pronounced than from the Faerie Dragon, it being tiny for example can change a lot.

Comment: a fey, fae, faerie, or fairy dragon all ways to say the same thing, it is related to pseudodragons and fey

Comment: would you allow a fey to get the fey touched feat

Comment: @faedragon Of course. Fey Touched has no restrictions. So anyone can use it. That's what I tried to say in my answer.

Comment:  thanks got it

Comment: also, I was just curious someone changed my question to something different,

Answer (score 6):

#### You need to ask your DM

There are no official rules anywhere in D&D 5th Edition that allow you to play a Faerie Dragon. If your DM has given you approval to use that as a playable race, you are *entirely* in homebrew territory with regard to what you can and cannot do with that race.

Because the Faerie Dragon is not an official playable race, there are naturally no official rules about how they relate to racial feats.

So, go talk to your DM. Tell them what you want to do, and see what they say. Also, just to err on the side of caution, make sure you've talked to your DM about using a homebrew race.

Comment: I have talked to him

Answer (score 4):

### "Homebrew problems require homebrew solutions"

You're starting off by playing a completely nonstandard character that's only possible because the DM is giving special permission to totally ignore the standard rules of the game.

You can't follow that up by asking what the rules say. You've created a situation for yourself that doesn't exist within the rules as written, so you can't now ask how it interacts with the rules as written. The answer has to be "it's up to your DM" because this whole scenario is up to your DM.

Comment: While this is a bit of an extreme situation, it often does make sense to ask how a piece of homebrew interacts with the other rules as written as long as the homebrew is well defined and precise. This site is filled with that type of question, many of which are good questions with good answers.

Comment: It's not a homebrew It is using the page in the monster book, plus other dnd info about fae or faerie dragons, and setting every thing else as a normal character

Comment: @faedragon Monster Manual creatures are not meant to be player characters, do not gain player classes, do not earn XP, do not level up, and cannot gain Feats unless the DM alters the monster for their own use. Using a Monster Manual creature as your leveling-up player character is absolutely homebrew--not the creature itself, but the conversion that turns it into a player character option.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman The fact that it's extreme is exactly what I'm referring to.  This isn't just a feat or spell to compare to the existing rules. "How does this character fit into character generation" is going to be a big mass of "ask the DM" because the rules simply don't contemplate how to make a random monster into a playable character.

Comment: I used it for the AC, Skills, speed, species abilities, languages, and senses, then set up the health, abilities, and class like a normal character